# EF Table-per-hierarchy mapping

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In trying to normalize a database schema and mapping it in Entity Framework, I've found that there might end up being a bunch of lookup tables. They would end up only containing key and value pairs. I'd like to consolidate them into one table that basically has two columns "Key" and "Value". For example, I'd like to be able to get Addresses.AddressType and Person.Gender to both point to the same table, but ensure that the navigation properties only return the rows applicable to the appropriate entity.

EDIT: Oops. I just realized that I left this paragraph out:

It seems like a TPH type of problem, but all of the reading I've done indicates that you start with fields in the parent entity and migrate fields over to the inherited children. I don't have any fields to move here because there would generally only be two.

There are a lot of domain-specific key-value pairs need to be represented. Some of them will change from time to time, others will not. Rather than pick and choose I want to just make everything editable. Due to the number of these kinds of properties that are going to be used, I'd rather not have to maintain a list enums that require a recompile, or end up with lots of lookup tables. So, I thought that this might be a solution.

Is there a way to represent this kind of structure in EF4? Or, am I barking up the wrong tree?

EDIT: I guess another option would be to build the table structure I want at the database level and then write views on top of that and surface those as EF entities. It just means any maintenance needs to be done at multiple levels. Does that sound more, or less desireable than a pure EF solution?

Comment: First of all, try to envision it from the Object side. You are talking Relational here.  How much sense would a family relation between AddressType and Gender make in your model?

Comment: I'm really not trying to create any kind of conceptual relation between between those two properties. All of the properties that I'm looking at have the same basic schema underneath: "key" and "value". I just want to be able to map multiple properties to the same underlying table structure. From the object side of things there would be no relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table per hiearchy demands that you have one parent entity which is used as base class for child entities. All entities are mapped to the same table and there is special discriminator column to differ type of entity stored in database record. You can generally use it even if your child entities do not define any new properties. You will also have to define primary key for your table otherwise it will be handled as readonly entity in EF. So your table can look like:

```
CREATE TABLE KeyValuePairs
(
  Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  Key VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Value NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  Discriminator VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  Timestamp Timestamp NOT NULL 
)
```

You will define your top level KeyValuePair entity with properties Id, Key, Value and Timestamp (set as concurrency mode fixed). Discriminator column will be used for inheritance mapping.

Be aware that EF mapping is static. If you define AddressType and Gender entities you will be able to use them but you will not be able to dynamically define new type like PhoneType. This will always require modifying your EF model, recompiling and redeploying your application.

From OOP perspective it would be nicer to not model this as object hiearchy and instead use conditional mapping of multiple unrelated entities to the same table. Unfortunatelly even EF supports conditional mapping I have never been able to map two entities to the same table yet.

Comment: I can't seem to get any columns other than ID to show up when I try to add a condition in the child entity.

Comment: @kettch: What do you mean by condition?

Comment: Maybe this is what you were saying you couldn't get working. After I add the inherited table, I go to add the conditional mapping and teh dropdown doesn't have anything other than the PK of the parent.

Comment: @kettch: Check this tutorial: http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-hierarchy-inheritance/